# Continue alignment to new page when using enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I would like to keep the sentence starting in Let w to be inline with the (ii). It is a continuation of the (ii). However it gets aligned with 2(b) instead.

I am using enumerate to get 2b and another enumerate within for (i), (ii).

What should I do to keep everything under (ii) to be aligned with the rest of text in (ii) even if it spans two pages?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Usually, we don't put "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: The enumerate environment can get mangled over page breaks, especially if you have `\pagebreak` between the `\item` statements. Probably Google for an answer, but SE will probably have the most answers.